# flatten a key from a collection of ruby json objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, render

I have this collection:

```
[#<Admin id: 1, enabled: true, created_at: "2013-11-11 18:15:20", updated_at: "2014-05-21 23:16:06"]
```

when I call

```
 render :json => @authors.sort_by {|author| author.enabled}
```

as expected I have the returned JSON:

```
[{"admin":{"created_at":"2013-11-11T18:15:20Z","enabled":true,"id":1,"updated_at":"2014-05-21T23:16:06Z"}}, {"admin":{}}]
```

is there a way to use rail's render function to flatten the json so my collection looks like this:

```
[{"created_at":"2013-11-11T18:15:20Z","enabled":true,"id":1,"updated_at":"2014-05-21T23:16:06Z"}, {}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render :json => @authors.sort_by {|author| author.enabled}.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the map function.

```
render :json => @authors.sort_by{|author| author.enabled}.map{|a| a["admin"]}
```